# Show that the polynomial $f = x^2 + 1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$. How many elements does $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(f)$ have?

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Show that the polynomial $f = x^2 + 1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$. How many elements does $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(f)$ have? Write out all of the elements of this field, and find the inverse of each nonzero element.

I am trying to show that the polynomial $f = x^2 + 1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$. To do so, I am using the following theorem: (Let $F$ be a field, $f \in F[x]$ of degree 2 or 3) If $f$ has no roots, then $f$ is irreducible. So, since $f(0), f(1)$ and $f(2)$ are all not $\equiv$ 0(mod 3), $f$ has no roots and thus $f$ is irreducible. Now how would I calculate how many elements $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(f)$ has? Would I need to find all of the polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ that don't have roots? I would appreciate any feedback!

Comment: Each class of $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(f)$ has a representative that is the remainder that its elements leave in the division by $f$. Since your $f$ has degree $2$, the remainder has degree at most $1$. So, it is determined by two coefficients that are in $\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: @topeik okay! so would the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(f)$ be all polynomials with degree 1 (i.e. $x + 1$, $x - 3$, $2x + 4$)?

Comment: Or degree $0$, like $1,2$, or degree $-\infty$, like $0$.

Comment: The roots of $x^2+1$ are $\pm i$ which certainly are not elements of $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$.

Comment: $\mathbb Z_3[x]/(f)$ is a field with $9$ elements

Answer (score 2):

The elements of $\mathbb Z_3[x]/(f)$ are $a+bx$ with $a,b\in\mathbb Z_3$.

There are $3$ possibilities for $a$ and $3$ for $b$, so $9$ elements altogether.

Note that in the quotient ring $x^2\equiv-1$.

The multiplicative inverse of $x$ is $2x$.  The inverse of $1+x$ is $2+x$.

I will leave the rest as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: For the 9 elements I got (with a = 1, 2, 3 and b = 1, 2, 3), $x + 1, 2x + 1, 3x + 1, 3x + 2, 2x + 2, x + 2, x + 3, 2x + 3$ and $3x + 3$. How does the quotient ring $x^2 \equiv -1$ relate to finding the inverse of each nonzero element in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(f)$?

Comment: Those $9$ elements are correct, though $x+3\equiv x$, $3x+3\equiv0$, etc.

Comment: $(x)(2x)=2x^2\equiv2(-1)=-2\equiv1$; $(1+x)(2+x)=2+3x+x^2\equiv2+0-1=1$

Comment: I am a little confused why you are multiplying $(x)(2x)$?

Comment: to demonstrate that inverse of $x$ is $2x$, show their product is $1$

Comment: Since $3x + 3$ is the only zero-element, would I need to find the inverse of all other 8 elements?

Comment: Yes; I gave inverses of two of them to get you started, and you probably know the inverses of $(3x+)1$ and $(3x+)2$ already

Comment: I am stuck on finding the inverses of the rest of the 4 elements. I have exhausted all possibilities $(2x + 1)(2x + 2), (2x + 1)(2), (2x + 1)(2)$ to no avail

Comment: You know the inverses of $1$ and $2$?  As I wrote, the inverse of $x$ is $2x$ (so the inverse of $2x$ is $x$) and the inverse of $1+x$ is $2+x$ (so the inverse of $2+x$ is $1+x$).  The only elements left are $1+2x$ and $2+2x$, and $(2x+1)(2x+2)=4x^2+6x+2\equiv x^2+2\equiv (x^2+1)+1\equiv1.$

Comment: For $(1)(2)$, I get $2 \equiv -1$ which is $\equiv$ to 1?

Comment: No, modulo $3, -1\equiv2$.  $1$ is its own inverse ($1\cdot1=1$), and modulo $3$ so is $2\equiv-1\; (2\cdot2=4\equiv1)$